# REST API and Identity Server 4 testing with Postman

Tags: api, rest, authentication, postman, identityserver4

I have a solution that has my web application, my REST API, and my Identity Server 4. All of which are now on .net 5. Locally everything works fine, but once I load everything up to the server, I get an error on Postman.

**Setup** - The API, and the IDP server are on separate sites.

**What I Know** - I know the IDP server works because I can get a token in Postman. I also know that the actual API works because when I remove the [Authorize] attribute from the controller I have, the call from Postman works fine.

**The Problem** - The problem that I have now is that when I put the [Authorize] attribute back in, I always get a 401 Unauthorized error for the API call. Below is the Startup file portion that sets up the authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "https://bob.com/API-IDP/";
                    options.ApiName = "BOBSAPI";
                    options.ApiSecret = "bobssecret";
                });
```

I also know that the Configure portion, that the order of the Use***** is correct. I've also tried tweaking with the AppPool settings, in terms of "Load Profile", all based on things I've found while searching. I've gone to the Identity 4 website and followed those examples as best as I can. Oh, one more thing. The IDP database has a table for PersistedGrants. I do see a few records in that table, which I think means the authentication worked? But if the authentication worked, then why did the API call return a 401? Is there something I need to do on the controller besides the [Authorization] attribute? I've spent 3 days on this and I'm pulling my hair out. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at the response headers of the response from the API and see if this header gives any clues to why you are not authorized:

For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2020 11:19:06 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
```

You should also make sure this flag is set to True in the AddJwtBearer config:

```
//True if token validation errors should be returned to the caller.
options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
```

You can use a tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to do that.

Then I would look at the ASP.NET Core logfile to determine why it does not accept your token.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I downloaded Fiddler and the response header doesn't contain anything revealing at all. In the request headers, I can see that the Bearer Token is there and it's correct. If I look in the Auth tab of the request the correct header is there. Also, I don't have the option of IncludeErrorDetails in the IdentityServer config.

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference or not, but we have the server set up as https://example.com, with a number of websites below it. So, the API is an application under https://example.com/API. And the Identity Server is set up as an application under https://example.com/IDP. It shouldn't matter that it's not the root site, should it?

Comment: How do you protect the API? you typically use AddJwtBearer to protect APIs and then you do get that header as I wrote earlier. Also, I typically recommend that you put IdentiyServer, your client and the API on different services domains, just to better understand when it does not work. When its all mixed together, its a pain to troubleshoot. next, I would increase the log level and look at the raw logs.

Comment: Cookies could be a problem if they have the path atttribute set.  Do inspect how the cookies are set.  next I would remove the authorize attribute and put a breakpoint in a action method and look if I actually have a user at all in the HttpContext.User
 object

Comment: Okay, question for you. For the AddJwtBearer, are you talking about in the setup file? I tried that before and it didn't work. However I didn't look at the response headers when I did that either, so I'll give that another shot. I know the API works when the authorize attribute is removed, but I hadn't thought about checking out the user. Good idea! I'll give that a shot too. Thanks!

Comment: I mean in the Startup class, what handler do you use to protect the API, you typically use AddJwtBearer for APIs. Do look for the WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error header. Also increase the log level in the API and explore the logs. I typically use Seilog and send the logs to an instance of Seq. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hi Tore - I am adding IdentityServerAuthentication to the startup file to secure it.

Comment: HI Tore - Here is what I did to test this, and I kept the IdentityServer as the authority to test it first. I fired up my local version of the API and used the identity server on my test server as the authority. I was able to get a token just fine. When I went to request data from the API, I could see an error in the console about it not being able to access the authority and that it didn't match what it was supposed to be. Turns out that I had a forward slash and my API name was in all caps. I made them match and it worked. I published the code to the server and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit, but with some help from Tore Nestenius, I was able to figure it out. Here's what I did with my final testing to get things working:

I used my Identity Server 4, hosted on our test server, as the authority. Then, I fired up my local API, so I could see the console. I was successful in getting the token, but when I went to request data through Postman, I got the same error about being unauthorized. I looked at the console and the error in the console basically said that the authority did not match what it was expecting. The difference turned out to be a forward slash. Once I made them match in my startup file, the API command worked.

The moral of the story here is make sure the authority you set up in your startup file is correct. If you are getting unauthorized issues, I would look there first.